# Including images to HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to upload a particular image on my HTML. The image is in the same folder, the HTML file is also in the same folder. However, it still doesn't show me the image when I access the image on HTML.
The code for the image tag in HTML is:

```
<img src="Layout.jpg" alt="Layout">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should work, is the image named `Layout.jpg`?

Comment: You should have a closing `/`: `<img src="Layout.jpg" alt="Layout"/>`. Furthermore, check the case of the file on the server - Windows servers ignore case, but Linux ones don't.

Comment: Tried both. Doesn't work :/. Also tried the closing /. Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your server. If your webpage is located at `http://example.com/path/to/my/html`, does the corresponding URL `http://example.com/path/to/my/Layout.jpg` work? It is possible that the server that you are using needs additional configuration to route the URL to the underlying image file. More details regarding your specific server / hosting platform would be needed to diagnose the issue.

Comment: The file is local. The server is on a Windows machine. I'm only trying to render an image by using    <img src="Layout.jpg> which means I'm trying to reference an object of jpg type in the same folder the html is in.

Comment: But which kind of server? For example, some servers need to be configured to serve files other than ones matching *.html. You may also need to look at the permissions of the file (if the file is not readable by the server, then there is no way for the server to read and render it).